# Store array in LocalStorage using Javascript and retrieve array from LocalStorage in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, local-storage

I'm storing array in localstorage using JavaScript. Now on other page I want to retrieve that array using Localstorage. For multiple items in array, I want to loop that data using php.

Following is my code:

PHP:

```
<?php
    $data = "<script>document.write(localStorage.getItem('cart'));</script>";
    echo $data; //Shows localstorage array items
    for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($data) ; $i++) { 
        echo $data[i]; //Cannot loop and display items
    }
?>
```

JavaScript:

```
function addTocart () {
    let items = ["1", "2"];
    localStorage.setItem('cart', items);
}
```

In my for loop, I get nothing. But `echo $data` shows items stored in localstorage.

Correct me please. Thanks!

Comment: You can't read the localStorage from the php file. you can store them in cookies... or just send the data with ajax to the php.

Comment: Thanks @Shibi, cookies work fine, I wanted to try it with localStorage. Thanks for help!